# Reading File Remotely in C++

Tags: c++, windows, unix, file

Is there way that I can read the file from remote server using fopen or any other api.

Thanks
Avinash

Comment: What is the type of the server? SMB? Web server?

Comment: what os are you using? What have you figured out so far?

Comment: Can't you just provide the canonical path to the file (e.g. "\\server\dir\file")?

Comment: @0A0A: That's a Windows form, mostly used to connect to SMB servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [libcurl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL). It is a rich library that can work many types of servers.

Comment: Would you use it for communications if implementing grid computing ?

Comment: @Stephane, I am not an expert in grid computing but I'd go for a CORBA  for remote services.